# Fortran: If statement with two commands on the same line

Tags: fortran

In fortran, in a single line, I want to execute two commands after an `if`, like shown below.

```
if (.true.) err = 'my error message' AND return
```

Is this possible? Using an `if (.true.) then ...` takes 4 whole lines!

Comment: `if (.true.) then; err = 'my error message'; return; end if`. This is one-line. There is no other way.

Comment: Yee, it takes 4 lines. Does it really matter?

Comment: Strive for clear code. That is not the same as concise code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@King has the answer:

```
if (.true.) then; err = 'my error message'; return; end if
```

Comment: Note that this is an IF construct and not an IF statement. (And also that I would reject this in any code review I was doing.)

Comment: I think one liners are sometimes more clear. Example: I'm reading an input [yaml file](https://github.com/BoldingBruggeman/fortran-yaml) to an atmospheric model and need to return an error like 30 different times, if a dictionary key in the input file does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

An IF statement is designed and specified specifically to conditionally execute a single (action) statement.

IF statements are not unique in rejected "joined statements"; nowhere in Fortran, unlike some other languages, is it possible to perform multiple statements as though they are one. (Some statements can be rewritten so that their combined effects can be accomplished in a single statement.)

An IF construct is precisely for the case of an executable block of one or more statements. And a wider variety of activities can be performed in an IF construct which isn't restricted to executing action statements.

To reflect what has been commented so far by others:

- an IF construct can be written on a single line (but really shouldn't be)
- the *intent* is much clearer in an IF construct than in some ersatz statement joining fashion
- Fortran is already a very verbose language and using four lines instead of one monster line shouldn't be regarded as a bad thing