# Simple Fortran if statement

Tags: if-statement, compiler-errors, fortran

```
program hi
    
    implicit none
    
    integer :: s=2
    if (s == 2) then print* 'hi' end if

end program hi
```

was expecting to get `hi` but instead I got

```
   13 | if (s == 2) then print* 'hi' end if
      |             1
Error: Syntax error in IF-clause after (1
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong and it's been doing the same error in all my assignments.

Answer (score 1):

Fortran's IF conditional aspect has two types: the IF *statement* and the IF *construct*.

You have an incorrect hybrid of the two.

And IF construct uses the IF-THEN-[ELSE...]-ENDIF form, but these parts are [separate statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71562819/3157076):

```
if (s==2) then
   print *, "hi"
end if
```

The IF statement does not have the THEN-ENDIF parts:

```
if (s==2) print*, "hi"
```

---

Note that you can put the separate statements of an IF construct on a [single line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67302648/3157076), but please don't.

Comment: Might also be that the missing "," after print * confuses the parser to think it's the if statement which is at fault.

Comment: I had assumed that the missing "," was a harmless part of the problem, but I didn't check. I've now checked and gfortran gives the same error message with and without it. (That error message itself depends on which version of gfortran but consistent each I've checked.)